# Replace Regex Multiple Matches between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to turn some text into html, but I'm having trouble building a table. Each cell is surrounded by brackets [].

I've already got the rows set:

```
<tr>[blue][red][yellow][purple][white]</tr>
```

Now I need to replace turn each cell into a `<td>`.

This would work fine:

```
.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g,'<td>$1</td>')
```

but I don't want to happen in other parts of the document, just when it's in between  tags.

This makes sense to me, but just doesn't work:

```
.replace(/(<tr>.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?\<\/tr\>)/g,'$1<td>$2</td>$3')
```

here is a full code if you want to try it:

```
alert('<tr>[blue][red][yellow][purple][white]</tr>'.replace(/(<tr>.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?\<\/tr\>)/g,'$1<td>$2</td>$3'));
```

it outputs:

```
<tr><td>blue</td>[red][yellow][purple][white]</tr>
```

expected output:

```
<tr><td>blue</td><td>red</td><td>yellow</td><td>purple</td><td>white</td></tr>
```

Comment: what is expected output? Is it last one?

Comment: Sorry should have included that, edited.

Comment: You'd better to traverse the HTML, find the tr's regularly and then apply the substitution (to their content). Searching the whole thing for specific tags with regex will be a problem

Comment: It would probably be easier, but I already am making a lot of replacements, and it would a lot less clean to have to loop through and make addition regex replacements, since right now I'm just looping through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily in two steps:

```
var str = "<div>[do not replace]</div><table><tr>[blue][red][yellow][purple][white]</tr></table>";

str = str.replace(/(<tr[\s\S]*?>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/tr>)/g, function(m, start, contents, end) {
    return start + contents.replace(/\[([\s\S]*?)\]/g, "<td>$1</td>") + end;
});

alert(str);
```

Note that I replaced what should have been `.` with `[\s\S]` to simulate the `s` regex option that JS unfortunately lacks.

Answer (score 0):

A way that use a split/join in the replacement function:

```
var str = '<tr>[blue][red][yellow][purple][white]</tr>';

var res = str.replace(/<tr>(?:\[[^\]]*\])+<\/tr>/g,
    function (m) {
        return '<tr><td>'
             + m.substring(5, m.length-6).split('][').join('</td><td>')
             + '</td><tr>';
    });

console.log(res);
```